# Why take crypto profits when you can just set a stop order?

Tags: cryptocurrency, profitability

In such a volatile market as cryptocurrency, I have heard many people stress the importance of taking profits. For example, when a coin doubles in value, they sell 50% of their holding. This ensures profitability (if a coin goes up) but results in the investor missing the peak. I was wondering, could stop orders be better?

For example, if each time a coin goes up 10%, an investor sets a stop order at 90-95% of the present value. That way, there is no sale if it keeps going up, and if it plummets, it ensures that you sell it close to the peak (90-95% of it). I never read about something like this online. What are some flaws with this strategy / thinking?

Comment: Use a trailing stop order though there's no guarantee that you'll get a fill at that price if it's a very volatile issue.

Comment: Why ever take any profit?

Comment: @BobBaerker unfortunately Coinbase Pro doesn’t offer that functionality :(

Comment: As a rule of thumb: The more stable and liquid a commodity is, the more closely its price will approximate a [continuous function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function) with respect to time. Unstable and/or illiquid commodities are not well approximated by continuous functions and therefore do not obey the [intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem). In other words, when the price changes abruptly, it does not pass through all intermediate prices, but may "jump" directly to a higher or lower value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The big issue is that there has to be a buyer. If BTC (or whatever you trade in) drops 20% very suddenly, your order might not be filled. There has to be someone willing to buy at that price, so a sudden decrease can leave orders unfilled. Your stop-orders can and many times will work to protect your gains, but they are not guarantees.

Comment: If I set a stop order for $1000 and the price suddenly drops to below that, wouldn’t it still execute? It would be at a lower price, but wouldn’t the transaction still occur?

Comment: @NickSolonko depends on exchange and mechanism used. Some have an option to trigger a sale at current market price when a threshold is reached. Others only place your sell order at a defined by you price when the threshold reaches. The latter means you will only sell at that price but also may not sell at all.

Comment: @NickSolonko And in that case, if it actually dropped to $500 before the order could be filled, there wouldn't be much protection on your gains.